# Entity Framework Core 2.2.6 Many-to-Many relationship (extra column at table creation)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to configure many-to-many relationship in Entity Core, based on that discussion:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368

After configuration database is created, with extra column (ProducerId in Movies table), as shown here:
[Movies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxFTj.png). On other side relationship in Producers table, there is no additional column, as shown here: [Producers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIPlG.png)

In project I have classes:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Person Director { get; set; }
    public TypesOfGenre Genre { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
    public Country CountryName { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> Actors { get; set; }

    //Configure enity:
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public IList<MovieProducer> MovieProducers { get; set; }
}

public class Producer
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime YearEstablished { get; set; }
    public long EstimatedCompanyValue { get; set; }
    public IList<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    //Configure enity:
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public IList<MovieProducer> MovieProducers { get; set; }
}
```

And I have joinig tabe:

```
public class MovieProducer
{
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }
    public Producer Producer { get; set; }

    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

All entities are configured in DbContext class including joining table:

```
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MovieProducer> builder)
 {
        builder.HasKey(k => new { k.ProducerId, k.MovieId });

        builder.HasOne(m => m.Movie)
               .WithMany(mp => mp.MovieProducers)
               .HasForeignKey(m => m.MovieId);

        builder.HasOne(p => p.Producer)
            .WithMany(mp => mp.MovieProducers)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProducerId);
 }
```

What is wrong with this configuration to create many to many relationship? There should be no extra column for ProducerId in Movies table.

Comment: every thing is ok and you don't have any mistak. in many to many relation between x and y we don't have one relation of x in y or vice versa.because we have many-to-many relation!!! you can access to Producer Table only with MovieProducers table from Movie table . hope you understand

Comment: Having `IList<Movie>` left in the Producer class effectively introduces another one-to-many. That is why `ProducerId` is added to the Movie table.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitar, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework Core 2.2 does not support many-to-many relations as EF6 does, so you should use 'MovieProducer' join table. Make sure to use 'virtual' for all your navigation properties and 'ICollection<>' instead of 'IList<>', e.g.:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Director { get; set; }
    public virtual TypesOfGenre Genre { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
    public virtual Country CountryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Actors { get; set; }
    //Configure enity:
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovieProducer> MovieProducers { get; set; }
}

public class Producer
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime YearEstablished { get; set; }
    public long EstimatedCompanyValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    //Configure enity:
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovieProducer> MovieProducers { get; set; }
}

public class MovieProducer
{
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Producer Producer { get; set; }

    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

and configuration for DbContext builder:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MovieProducer> builder)
{
   builder.Entity<Movie>(entity => {
      entity.HasKey(m => m.Id);

      // ...
   });

   builder.Entity<Producer>(entity => {
      entity.HasKey(p => p.Id);

      // ...
   });

   builder.Entity<MovieProducer>(entity => {
      entity.HasKey(mp => new { mp.ProducerId , mp.MovieId });

      entity.HasOne(mp => mp.Producer)
            .WithMany(p => p.MovieProducers)
            .HasForeignKey(mp => mp.ProducerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // Restrict or Cascade

      entity.HasOne(mp => mp.Movie)
            .WithMany(p => p.MovieProducers)
            .HasForeignKey(mp => mp.MovieId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // Restrict or Cascade
   });
}
```

Do not forget to use 'add-migration' and 'update-database' to add changes to database.